# Laravel 5.2 how to update my User table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to update my rows. The figure provided is the Users table structure. When I register using Laravel Authentication. Only the yellow marked rows are used and others remain empty. I have a created another page called profile and want to add data to the remaining empty rows using a profile page. But I am stuck and can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

[image: user table structure]

Comment: Update your question for precision and more details. Share what you've done by far and the challenge faced for possible resolutions.

Comment: Please be more detailed with your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create Profile controller for interaction with User table from profile page, like this:

```
use App\User;
class ProfileController extends Controller {
public function function_name(Request $request)
  { 
    ...
    $user = Auth::User(); //get authorized user, or you can get user by ID
    $user->city = 'City';
    $user->country = 'Country ';
    $user->save();
    ...

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your user model, dont forget to add thoes fields to fillable variable;

for exemple

```
  protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'company_name','street_name','whatever'
    ];
```

this way the `->create($data);` method will work just fine

or you can just add those fields to registration form and update your registration method